# Does changing the default program for opening a specific file affects the computer behavior?

Tags: command-line, default-settings, file-types

I have some `.java` files that I want to view/edit in Notepad++, but I am not sure how this will affect other programs. Would the compiler still be able to compile them, or would I find some issues?

I would check .java files, but I would like to change some other types to be opened with Notepad++. And I dont want to go back and change every type back to "default" program.

Can I set one rule for double click and another rule for command line for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the default program to open a file extension won't affect the behaviour of other programs that use that file, so opening your `.java` files in Notepad++ won't be a problem when compiling them.

If in command line, you can use the program name if you want to open with a different program than the default, for example:

```
notepad.exe test.html
```

As long as `notepad.exe` is a recognized PATH, of course.